# Oracle HTTP Server Ubuntu Installation

Tags: oracle, http, installation, server

I have a problem about Oracle HTTP Server installation on Ubuntu system.I read release notes and installation guides all information about Linux EE editions Redhat atc. I have an error during the installation process said Checking installation system certification (unchecked).I saw required package information about Linux EE versions but cant find about Ubuntu distro. Anyone know which package I need?

This is my error message during my installation:

*Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed
Problem: Some recommended packages are missing (see above).
Recommendation: You may actually have installed packages which have obsoleted these, in which case you can successfully continue with the install. If you have not, it is recommended that you do not continue. Refer to the product release notes to find out how to get the missing packages and update the system.*

Comment: Oracle does not certify or support software on Ubuntu. It is a completely different branch of the Linux family from Oracle Linux and Red Hat. You need to use a supported operating system to find the required packages or be able to get accurate support from this forum or from Oracle.

Comment: @pmdba I guess there only way to work with supported operating systems.But they should write this to documentation.Thanks!

Comment: The did write it to the documentation.  Start at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/core/install-ohs/GUID-16F78BFD-4095-45EE-9C3B-DB49AD5CBAAD.htm#ASINS325

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks! Here is the documentation https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/fusion-certification.html